# Number of images formed by two plane mirrors formulae derivation.

Tags: geometry, physics

**Derive:**

> Number of images formed by two plane mirrors inclined at an angle of $\theta$ is given by
> $$\frac{360}{\theta} -1 $$

**What I think:**
Inclined mirror forms images in the circle and one image lies in one sector.

No of images = Number of sectors=$\frac{360}{\theta}$

And $1$ is subtracted from $\frac{360}{\theta}$ because a sector is occupied by the object.

*I think this is not a proper derivation. How to prove that
Inclined mirror forms images in the circle?*

I saw an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670690/820922) but I didn't understand it.

How to derive it formally?

---

**What's correct:**
Let $$n=\dfrac{360}{\theta}$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the two mirrors

*If $n$ is even:*
$$\mathrm{Number\ of\ images}=n-1$$
*If $n$ is odd and the object is placed symmetrically:*
$$\mathrm{Number\ of\ images}=n-1$$
*If $n$ is odd and the object is **not** placed symmetrically:*
$$\mathrm{Number\ of\ images}=n$$
*If $n$ is in decimal then only integral part is taken and above rules are followed.*

It should be noted that above the 'number of images' means the number of images formed.

---

**Experiment work:**

$\color{red}{\theta=30^\circ}$

[image: 30]

*Simulator:*

[image: 30s]

---

**Plus corner:**
I don't think there exists a derivation to the above formulae. Maybe it was found by experiments.
Note: A very tiny change in the angle can [spilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt3Zx.gif) the farthest image.

Comment: This is not true if $\frac{360}{\theta}$ is odd and object is not on bisector.

Comment: to prove my point, try with an angle of $24^\circ$ or $72^\circ$ and place the object somewhere other than bisector.

Comment: I upvoted to reverse a downvote.  The OP clearly showed good work that may or may not have been accurate.  In fact, regardless of whether the OP's analysis is accurate, even if there had not been a downvote, I would have upvoted: the problem is complicated, the OP showed good work, and his presentation was nicely formatted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove the number of images of two mirrors inclined at $A$ is $360/A -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670622/how-to-prove-the-number-of-images-of-two-mirrors-inclined-at-a-is-360-a-1)

Comment: For more information read [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/54160/2020/9/23) and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/113360/2020/9/24).

Answer (score 3):

Reflection of light in mirror is the same as reflection of the world in the mirror. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3825966/823370)

So, just do that... Let us consider your $\theta=60^o$. The original setup looks like this...

[image]

Now... REFLECT THE WORLD !!!!

[image]

There you go! Cheers :)

Comment: Great response and visuals. Some things to watch out for is in the cases when $\frac{180}{\theta}$ are not integers, which the answer OP linked for briefly discusses. I'm not sure if this is true, but I tried with $\theta=40$ and got 18 images by continuously reflecting (https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/smy6jdqf). I believe it makes sense that if $\frac{360}{n}\in Z$ and $v_2(n)>2$, then the number of images is $\frac{720}{\theta}-1$.

Comment: I think this was a correct proof. Though this shouldnt be used as an empirical formula. We have a method for it too... And also this doesnt work if the object is on the bisector (bcz you cannot join the reflected object by straight line in that case) or theta is not a divisor of 360. So, go with the method and not formulas in this case. If you wish to see that, you need to post another question regarding it.

Comment: @Mayank What do you mean by observing it. I think the explanation Soumyadwip provided is sufficient. It's clear that as you continuously reflect the entire environment, you can only get 5 images because the sectors are a divisor of 180.

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda Could you elaborate why it doesn't work when the object is on the angle bisector?

Comment: You can use this [simulator](https://ricktu288.github.io/ray-optics/simulator/)

Comment: The formula has too many cases. It doesnt hold for many cases. I just tried to justify your question. But I don't say that it is correct. And when you have a method, why do you go for a formula?

Comment: You were asking the derivation of an incomplete formula. I presented the case where it is correct.

Comment: 9 when placed asymetrically and 8 when symmetrically on the angle bisector

Comment: I don't get what you mean by reflect the 'world'. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.